# How http ensure the response data belong to which request when keep-alive is on

Tags: http, browser, tcp

http header connection:keep-alive allow multi requests share the same socket to reduce the tcp cost on creation and destroy, so the same socket will receive the response data that belong to each individual request. my question is how http protocol define this part, how response data find its related request, or it something outside http

Answer (score 0):

HTTP/1 (where keep-alive is relevant) has a clearly defined message format which makes it possible to determine when a request and respond end and a new one starts - see [RFC 7230 Message Format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3) for the details. An application needs to understand this message format when handling HTTP.

Comment: Thanks, I read the section of connection persistence and that make sense, one request must be read complete then start a new one, that will make it accurate. but  what confuse me is the web page allow multi request send parallel, I can send requests with connection:keep-alive tag, so they are little conflict. then I  did a try and I notice there are multi sockets created at beginning, not one. this  should be a socket pool, the follow up request will find a available socket which complete its response and reuse it or create a new one if no one available

Comment: @baotongw: yes, with HTTP/1 browsers open multiple connections to the server since each connection can only handle a single request at one time (i.e. multiple requests only one after the other). With HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 this is different - here interleaving requests is possible within a single connection.